# How to make one of a rectangle's sides marked using GUI in Java (SWT only)?

Tags: java, user-interface, geometry, swt

Given the following code :

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class BasicShapes {

    private Shell shell;

    public BasicShapes(Display display) {    
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.addPaintListener(new ExmaplePaintListener());
        shell.setText("Basic shapes");
        shell.setSize(430, 300);
        shell.setLocation(300, 300);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ExmaplePaintListener implements PaintListener {

        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {    
            drawRectangles(e);
            e.gc.dispose();
        }
    }

    private void drawRectangles(PaintEvent e) {    
        e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
        e.gc.setBackground(new Color(e.display, 150, 150, 150));    
        e.gc.fillRectangle(20, 20, 120, 80);
        e.gc.fillRectangle(180, 20, 80, 80);
        e.gc.fillRectangle(280,20,100,79);
    }    
}
```

In the above code I create 3 rectangles , and I want to make one of the rectangle's sides to be marked / color it with a different color , or in other words , to have the ability to pick each one of a rectangle's sides , and mark it . Is it possible ?

Regards,Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `fill`ing the rectangle, just `draw` a line on one of its sides.
For example:

```
e.gc.fillRectangle(280, 20, 100, 79);
e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE)); //Set the edge color
e.gc.drawLine(280,20, 280+100,20); //Modify this to print
                                   //another side of the rectangle.
```

---

**Note:** if you want to draw *all* of the sides, it's obviously better to just:

```
e.gc.fillRectangle(280, 20, 100, 79);
e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE)); //Set the edge color
e.gc.drawRectangle(280, 20, 100, 79);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , but there's a problem with the line "e.gc.setColor(Color.BLUE);" , I get a compilation error , since there is no "BLUE" . Any idea what's wrong with that ?

Comment: I'm done my friend , thanks . The solution is : " 
        e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));"  thanks a lot again !

Comment: Sorry, I confused AWT with SWT! Editing answer.